# main.js is not loading in my Vue 3 project

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vuejs3, webpack-5

Recently I upgraded my project from vue2 to vue3, also I upgraded the webpack to version 5.
Now my main.js file is not loading.
Do anyone had a same problem?

I tried everything available in the stackoverflow but it didn't worked for me.

This is my config file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
const openInEditor = require('launch-editor-middleware');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const resolveClientEnv = require('./src/util/resolveClientEnv');
const paths = require('./src/util/paths');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js?v=[fullhash:6]',
  },
  externals: {
    Moyasar: 'Moyasar',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[fullhash]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
      '@': paths.resolve('src'),
    },
    extensions: ['.*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: './index.html',
    },
    devMiddleware: {
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    onBeforeSetupMiddleware: (app) => {
      app.app.use('/__open-in-editor', openInEditor());
    },
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'template.html',
      inject: true,
    }),
    new DefinePlugin({
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: 'true',
      __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'false',

      ...resolveClientEnv({
        publicPath: '/',
      }),
    }),
  ],
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: 'warn',
  },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
  module.exports.devtool = 'source-map';
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"',
      },
    }),
    new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ]);
}
```

Am I missing something in my configurations file?

Also I am not able to access my files as I open the file by url.
e.g 'localhost:8080/src/assets/favicon.png'.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code? Without it it is gonna be hard to help

Comment: Yeah sure, I added the config file.

Comment: Vue3 performs better with vite rather webpack. Give it a try.